# Sidebar on the wrong side of the page

Tags: sidebar

I'm building a website on WordPress through a child theme based on [Dazzling](https://br.wordpress.org/themes/dazzling/). The website is http://theaerogeek.com/

The problem I'm having is that the sidebar of my website is being shown on the right side, even though on the theme's configuration on WordPress dashboard it is set to be on the left.

The problem seemed to arise when I uploaded the header.php file (I'm not sure if it was when I created header.php or when I created style.css). When I inspect the page, the tag that contains the sidebar (widget area) is div#secondary.widget-area.col-sm-12.col-md-4 . However, I can't find this tag neither on the header.php nor the style.css. Does anyone know how to fix the problem?

Comment: Do you want to keep the option of moving sidebar to the right / left? Or you do not care about that and you just need the sidebar to be on the left. I looked at your website, the problem occurred when you changed the `header.php` file.

Comment: If I could keep the option to move, it would be good, but I don't mind have it fixed on the left. Do you know what the problem is specifically?

Comment: You deleted the code in `header.php` that read the option and set the appropriate CSS class. Can you paste `header.php` code?

Comment: it is too long to paste it here. Is there anyway I can send it to you?

Comment: use for example [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/), account is not needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just checked your site, if you want to move the sidebar to the left, add this to your CSS.

```
@media (min-width:992px) {
 .col-md-1,.col-md-10,.col-md-11,.col-md-12,.col-md-2,.col-md-3,.col-md-4,.col-md-5,.col-md-6,.col-md-7,.col-md-8,.col-md-9 {
  float:right;
 }
}
```

[image]

In case you don't know how to add CSS, [check this out](https://en.support.wordpress.com/custom-design/editing-css/).

Comment: Thanks mate! It worked like a charm! Do you mind if ask what does the css code does? I don't know what .col-md classes do...

Comment: Check this reading. https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_examples.asp